# what console.log with ','(comma) do in output of javascript. Iam using nodejs

Tags: javascript, object, output, console.log

Really cant understand why it is printing additional 0 and not giving error.I cant write anything in console log without quotes  unless and until it is not predefined. Also i attached the photo of code and Output.

**Here you can see normal output without comma and then with comma it add extra 0 with fruit quality.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyzZv.jpg   Normal Output

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR8OO.jpg  With Comma in console log in line 8

Please Help.....

Comment: Please edit & add the code/results to the question rather than posting screenshots.

Comment: because you are doing `+" "`

Comment: You have to put the commas in quotes as well, you want them to be strings.

Answer (score 0):

The [Unary plus](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.7) is converting an empty string into a number.

```js
console.log(+" ")
```